# ReactJS : How to handle image undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, axios

I have a status 500 server error, I know the cause of this error is when I don't give an image to my form.
And I can see in my console : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined`

I have two questions:

- How to handle this error?

OR

- How to set a default image if no image is given ?

I have a lot of trouble understanding the whole image system because my project must remain as RESTFULL as possible.

Here's the code to help me resolve the first error :
The route of Produit

```
// -- The Route of produitRoute
const authenticateJWT = require('../services/authentification')

const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const path = require('path');
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname + '../../../public/'));
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, `${uuidv4()}.${file.originalname.split('.').pop()}`);
    }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

module.exports = app => {
    const produitController = require('../controller/produitController');
    const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

    const validatorHandler = (req, res, next) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json(errors.array())
        }
        next();
    };

    // Permet la création d'un produit
    app.post('/api/produit/create', authenticateJWT,
    body('nom')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Vous devez donner un nom au produit.'),
    body('prix')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Le produit doit avoir un prix.')
        .isDecimal()
        .withMessage('Le prix doit être uniquement composé de nombre.')
        .isFloat({min: 1, max: 100000})
        .withMessage('Le prix du produit doit être compris entre 1 et 100 000'),
    body('imageurl')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Le produit doit avoir une image.'),
    body('qtestock')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Une quanité doit être indiquée pour le produit.')
        .isDecimal()
        .withMessage('La quantité du produit doit être composé de nombre.')
        .isFloat({min: 1, max: 100000})
        .withMessage('La quantité du produit doit être compris entre 1 et 100 000'),
    body('marqueId')
        .notEmpty()
        .withMessage('Le produit doit appartenir à une marque.'),
    validatorHandler, produitController.create);

    app.post('/api/produit/addImage', authenticateJWT,  upload.single('imageFile'), produitController.addImage);
```

At first, I thought I could put an validator from express-validator on my image route but its doesn't seem to work so I gave up on the idea.

The controller of ProduitRoute

```
// The Controller of ProduitController
const { Sequelize } = require('../config/db.config');
const db = require('../config/db.config');
const Produits = db.produits;
const {Op} = require('sequelize');

// Permet la création d'un produit
exports.create = (req, res) => {

    const { nom, prix, description, imageurl, qtestock, marqueId } = req.body;

    Produits.create({
        nom: nom,
        prix: prix,
        description: description,
        imageurl: imageurl,
        qtestock: qtestock,
        marqueId: marqueId
    }).then(produit => {
        res.json(produit);
    }).catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
};

exports.addImage = (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        url: req.file.filename
    });
};
```

My Axios request

```
// My Axios request - produit
import axios from 'axios';

// Url de base
const APIURL = 'http://localhost:8090/api';
const Token = localStorage.getItem('UserToken')


export const createProduit = (nom, prix, description, imageurl, qtestock, marqueId) => axios.post(`${APIURL}/produit/create`,
{
    nom: nom,
    prix: prix,
    description: description,
    imageurl: imageurl,
    qtestock: qtestock,
    marqueId: marqueId,
});

export const addImage = (formData) => axios.post(`${APIURL}/produit/addImage`, formData, {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
});
```

And my produitPage (Form)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Grid, TextField, Avatar, Button, Typography, Link, Card} from '@material-ui/core';
import AddCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircle';
import CheckIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';

// Import 
import {createProduit, addImage, getProduitById} from '../services/API/produit'
import {getAllMarque} from '../services/API/marque';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ProduitPage() {
    const { id } = useParams();

    // Classe de style
    const classeProduit = ProduitStyle();

    const history = useHistory();

    const [errorForm, setErrorForm] = useState([]);
    const [produit, setProduit] = useState(null);

    // Création d'un user
    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (produit) {
            // mettre à jour
        } else {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('imageFile', event.target.imageurl.files[0]);
            addImage(formData).then(response => {
                if (response.data){
                    createProduit(event.target.nom.value, event.target.prix.value, event.target.description.value, response.data.url, event.target.qtestock.value, event.target.marqueId.value)
                        .then(() => {
                            history.push({
                                pathname: '/admin',
                            });
                        }).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err.response.data);
                            setErrorForm(err.response.data);
                        });
                } else {
                    //erreur
                }
    
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    };

    // Les erreurs du formulaires
    const erreurAffiche = errorForm.map((uneError) => (
        <div style={{color: 'red'}} >
            {uneError.msg}
        </div>

    ))


    // Récupération des marques
    const [marques, setMarques] = React.useState([])
    const getMarque = () => [
        getAllMarque().then(response => {
            setMarques(response.data)
        })
    ]

    // Chargement
    useEffect(() => {
        getMarque()

        if (id) {
            getProduitById(id).then(response => {
                if (response.data){
                    setProduit({
                        nom: response.data.nom,
                        prix: response.data.prix,
                        description: response.data.description,
                        qtestock: response.data.qtestock,
                        marqueId: response.data.marqueId
                    })
                }
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <Grid>
            <Card style={{height: 700, marginTop: '5%', marginRight: '10%',  marginLeft: '10%'}} variant="outlined">

                <Grid align="center">
                    <Avatar className={classeProduit.avatar}><AddCircleIcon></AddCircleIcon></Avatar>
                    <h2>{produit ? "Modification" : "Création"} d'un produit :</h2>
                    {erreurAffiche}
                </Grid>

                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <TextField style={TextFieldStyle} id='nom' name='nom' label='Nom produit :' placeholder='Entrez le nom du produit' type='string' fullWidth required variant='outlined' />
                    <TextField style={TextFieldStyle} id='prix' name='prix' label='Prix du produit :' placeholder='Entrez un prix' type='decimal' fullWidth required variant='outlined'  />
                    <TextField style={TextFieldStyle} id='description' name='description' label='Description du produit :' placeholder='Entrez une description' type='string' multiline row={6} fullWidth required variant='outlined' />
                    <input
                        accept='image/*'
                        id="imageurl"
                        name='imageurl'
                        type="file"
                    />
                    <TextField style={TextFieldStyle} id='qtestock' name='qtestock' label='Quantité restante du produit :' placeholder='Entrez une quantitée' type='decimal' fullWidth required variant='outlined' />
                    <InputLabel>Le produit appartient à : </InputLabel>
                    <Select
                        native
                        inputProps={{
                            name: 'nomMarque',
                            id: 'marqueId',
                        }}
                        
                        >
                            {marques.map((marque) => (
                            <option key={marque.id} value={marque.id}>
                                {marque.nom}
                            </option>
                            ))}

                    </Select>
                    <Button endIcon={<CheckIcon/>} className={classeProduit.root} type='submit' variant='contained' fullWidth>Créer</Button>
                </form>

                <Typography>
                    <Link href='/admin'>
                        Retourner à la page d'administration.
                    </Link>
                </Typography>
            </Card>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

I have not yet managed the function of updating a product, that's why some places are empty.

And yes to create a product, it is in two requests, first the image (which is the cause of the error) then the rest of the product (name, price ...)

And this is the package I used to get my image : `npm install path multer uuid`

I'm still new to ReactJS but if anyone need more information I will do my best to anwser or to add more in my post !

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Use the image upload as a middleware class in your route like this

```js
router.post('/addShop',ImageUploadController.uploadImage('./uploads/shops','shopImage'),verify,routes.addShop)
```

This is how I handle my incoming imagers

```js
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs");

class ImageUploadController {
  // upload image to the server
  uploadImage(path, fieldName) {
    //check file dir path
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {   //if not exist create the path
      fs.mkdirSync(path);
    }
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, path);
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
      },
    });

    const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
      if (file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg") {
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb(null, false);
      }
    };

    const upload = multer({
      storage: storage,
      limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10,
      },
      fileFilter: fileFilter,
    });

    return upload.single(fieldName);
  }
}

exports = module.exports = new ImageUploadController();
```

And this is my endpoint

```js
const addShop = (req, res, next) => {
  let imageDate = req.file ? req.file.path : "uploads\\default_image.jpeg";
  ...
```